# Google Oauth signin page returning 500 error with electron

Tags: google-oauth

I have an electron project which I am hoping to integrate Google in. When using the signin flow the inital page returns a 500 error with no details on the error. If I paste the link into my browser the page loads just fine so I know it's not the parameters.

Error:

*500. That’s an error. There was an error. Please try again later. That’s all we know.*

The relevant code:

```
const urlParams = {
    response_type: 'code',
    redirect_uri: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000',
    client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    scope: 'profile email',
}
const authUrl = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?${qs.stringify(urlParams)}

authWindow.loadURL(authUrl)
```

This code worked before I updated to electron 2.0.0 and it did work once afterwards so I'm not convinced it's that. There aren't any relevant differences in the request headers between electron and chrome.

I couldn't even find where to submit a bug report for this so wondering if anyone has any ideas?